# Is it a matter of style or correctness?

Tags: sentence-construction

Is the following question is a matter of style or correctness?

I'm not sure what the correct structure is:

> There are many definitions for this word **in the dictionary**.

Vs.

> There are many definitions **in the dictionary** for this word.

What's more clear, understandable or coherent?

Comment: In this case, definitely not correctness. Probably not even style, just personal preference.

Comment: They are both correct.  There is a tiny bit of difference of emphasis: with interchangeable phrases, you often put the one you want to emphasize at the end of the sentence, so the first sentence emphasizes the **dictionary** (and its thoroughness) and the second sentence emphasizes the **word** (and its many definitions).  But that difference is *very* subtle and would depend more on intonation if you were speaking the sentences.

Comment: Google Ngrams shows that 'definitions for' and 'definitions of' are used almost exactly as often, but there are no results for either 'definitions for this word in' or 'definitions in the dictionary for'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are grammatical.

The difference might be considered just one of personal preference, but it could also fall under a specific type of writing style called [**plain language**](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tcdnstyl-chap?lang=eng&lettr=chapsect13&info0=13).

In brief, plain language concerns itself with composing text as short and direct as possible while retaining its essential meaning.

To talk about plain language, I actually have to shift your emphasis from **in the dictionary** to **this word**. However, plain language does concern itself with structure, so my answer should still be relevant.

In this comparison, I would say that the subject of the sentence is **this word**, while the rest of the sentence says things *about* the word. (No doubt previous sentences will have defined which word it is.)

The closer **this word** is to the start of the sentence, the sooner it is recognized as the subject, and the more direct the sentence.

> There are many definitions in the dictionary for this word.

In this version, you only get to **this word** at the end—at which point you have to "back up" a bit for the context. (Mentally, the thought process might go something like "Oh, you're actually talking about the word here. What was it about the word again?")

> There are many definitions for this word in the dictionary.

In this version, **this word** is mentioned in the middle of the sentence, so it is already established as the subject by the time the sentence is finished. There is no need for that slight mental pause.

But an even *more* direct and easily parsed version of the sentence would be:

> This word has many dictionary definitions.

Not only does it bring **this word** to the very start of the sentence, but it also replaces the four-word prepositional phrase *definitions in the dictionary* with the simpler *dictionary definitions*.

The sentence is shorter and, therefore, more easily understood all at once. 
Note that the meaning is slightly altered in this version. If a *particular* dictionary had been part of the previous text, then dropping the article in front of it might not be appropriate.

But if the meaning *is* okay, it could be simplified even more—if one assumes that word definitions are always in dictionaries:

> This word has many definitions.

Finally, compare the two most stylistically different versions of the sentence:

> There are many definitions in the dictionary for this word.
>   This word has many definitions.

Does one sound better than the other? Is there a relevant loss of meaning between the two?

There are many people who do nothing but edit according to plain language. But choosing to follow the plain language style, unless it's a requirement, is also a matter of personal preference.